# ApiControllerAttribute and optional parameters

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-apicontroller

Read all the advantages of using `ApiControllerAttribute`, however, if we want to have optional parameter while using this attribute for query parameter, it doesn't work. It still validates all parameters as mandatory. Any idea how to make it optional?

```
[ApiController]    
public class testController: ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("employees/{id?}")]
    public List<Employees> GetAll(int? id)
    {
        // gets all employees or by id
    }
}
```

When this code is executed, it expects `id` all the time. It does not run without this parameter.

EDIT: it doesnt work even when default value of id is passed.

Comment: Add a default value `[HttpGet("employees/{id?}")]
public List<Employees> GetAll(int? id = null)`

Comment: Well, tried that, it still says "The value 'null' is not valid" 400 error. This is because ApiController does the validation. If I remove it, it works fine. I just want to know, how to make it work with ApiController attribute.

Comment: Maybe  docs here might help in understanding ApiController  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/

Comment: What is your .net core version? I made a test with `netcoreapp2.2`, it works correctly with `[HttpGet("employees/{id?}")]`. Share us a mini demo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: .net core version 2.1.603. I read that documentation, however, it didnt work thats why this question. Could it be the version?

Comment: Share us a mini demo, it works with built-in template .net core 2.1.

Comment: it turned out that this was a swagger issues, rather than the .net core web api issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764769/swagger-web-api-optional-query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Give a route to your ApiController

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReposController : ControllerBase
{
   //GetAll api/repos
   public IEnumerable<Employees> Getall()
   {
   //Your code
   }

    //GET api/repos/id
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Getid")]
    public Employees GetEmployees(int id)
    {
    //Your code
    }

}
```

Hope it helps