# Swagger not handling .net core optional parameter correctly

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, optional-parameters

I've got a Web API controller method that has an optional parameter like so:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getOrder/{price?}")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> Get(int? price = null)
{
}
```

However, when running the API, the Swagger UI shows the parameter as required and I can't call the method without the parameter. Why is this and how can I resolve it so that it's handle as an optional parameter?

[image]

Comment: check [this](https://www.seeleycoder.com/blog/optional-route-parameters-with-swagger-asp-net-core/) or [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/406)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger - Web API - Optional query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764769/swagger-web-api-optional-query-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [@CodingMytra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9247039/codingmytra)'s suggestion if you don't want to modify any SwaggerGen configurations could be to break the GET Web API controller into two distinct methods: one where the price is required in the route and another where it is an optional query parameter

As an example:

```
// endpoint #1 with required route param
[HttpGet]
[Route("Products/getOrder/{price}")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> Get1(int price)
{
    //... 
}

// endpoint #2 with optional params passed in via query string
[HttpGet]
[Route("Products/getOrder")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> Get2([FromQuery]int price)
{
    //...
}
```

Which will produce the following Swagger documentation:
[Products/getOrder/{price}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQUIs.png) and [Products/getOrder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VZbo.png).

The benefit of using query params being that you can reduce or expand search criteria in the future without changing the endpoint route.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[HttpGet("getOrder")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int? price = null)
{
}
```