# How can I document query string parameters with Swashbuckle?

Tags: c#, xml, documentation, query-string, swashbuckle

Swashbuckle does a great job of extracting C# XML comments to make Swagger API documentation.  And Swagger supports documenting query string parameters.  But if there's a way to document query string parameters in XML so Swashbuckle will export them, I haven't found it.

I have something like:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// List all users
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="?search">String to search for in user IDs and names</param>
    /// <returns>An array of users</returns>
    /// <response code="200">OK</response>
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<User>))]
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult ListUsers()
    {
        IEnumerable<User> users;

        // "?search=<substring>" in the URI searches for users
        // Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656841
        var searchString = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
            .Where(nv => nv.Key == "search")
            .Select(nv => nv.Value)
            .DefaultIfEmpty("")
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

And `search` does not show up in the output. I tried removing the `?` and that didn't help.  I suspect that the XML comments just don't support this directly.  If that's true, I'm looking for a Best Practice work around.  I'm considering adding a couple of bullets in a `<remarks>` block.  Any better ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add a `search` parameter to the `ListUsers` method?

Comment: If there is a way to add query string parameters as optional parameters to the `ListUsers()` method that could work but I'm relatively new to C#.Net and don't know (how) to do that.

Comment: `public IHttpActionResult ListUsers(string search)` should do the trick. It will be set from the query string.

Comment: There's a similar problem (and solution): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828328/adding-query-string-params-to-my-swagger-specs

Answer (score 2):

@jps pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks!

I ended up with:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// List all users
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="search">String to search for in user IDs and names</param>
    /// <returns>An array of users</returns>
    /// <response code="200">OK</response>
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<User>))]
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult ListUsers([Optional]string search)
    {
        IEnumerable<User> users;

        var searchString = search == null ? string.Empty : search;
```